# How do I "remove" a header-cell spot in AG Grid?

Tags: ag-grid

Is there any way to replicate the following table in AG Grid? I know how to do the multi-header (header D), but I can't figure out how to make it so that there is nothing above column A (left of header D).

[image]

Note: I'm using AG Grid in React.